# Coupling & Cohesion Design

Tags: java

This is a common situation I always faced during development work. For each modules, I will have to retrieve a list of users belonging to the respective department. ie. Human Resource / Finance / Purchasing

Should the retrieval of user logic be centralized at com.company.user module or I should have each respective module to retrieve the required users. ie. each module talks to the USER_TABLE ?

Based on my understanding of cohesion / coupling and DRY principle. I think the right way should of implementing this all the logic of retrieval of user by role should be centralized in the user package.

Am I correct to implement as such?

Package Level

```
com.company.financial
com.company.humanresource
com.company.purchasing
com.company.user
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component-based_software_engineering

Comment: I think this question is more appropriate for programmers.stackexchange.com or code review stack exchange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you right. Packaging by feature is more modular than packaging by layer,

so the package:

```
com.company.user
```

can holds the following classes:

```
UserGUI.java // gui class for adding users
User.java    // user model
UserDAO.java // user data access object
UserAction.java // controllers
```

Useful article:
[Package by feature, not layer](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=205)

Answer (score 3):

Yes I think you are right. Retrieval of user logic should be in the user package